# Derivative of matrix product: is it true that $\frac{d}{dt}(A^TA) = 2A^T \frac{dA}{dt}$?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

$A$ is a square matrix.  All elements of $A$ depend on a parameter $t$, that is, $a_{ij}=a_{ij}(t)$.  Let $S(A):=A^TA$, and take the derivative of $S$ w.r.t. $t$:
$\displaystyle \frac{dS}{dt}$

Now, pretty clearly

$\displaystyle \frac{dS}{dt} = \frac{dA^T}{dt}A + A^T\frac{dA}{dt}$

But now, can this also be written $\displaystyle \frac{dS}{dt} = 2 A^T \frac{dA}{dt}$  ?

A math text I am working though right now -- if I am reading it right -- implies that this is the case, but I haven't been able to prove it myself.

Thanks.

Comment: The function $S(t)=A^{T}A$ is a symmetric matrix for all $t$, and the derivative must have that property, too. Your expression has that property, but the proposed alternative does not.

Comment: It's true if $A$ is symmetric, which may be the case in the math text that you are reading.

Comment: The accepted answer presents some interesting concrete computations but its answer to the main question is incorrect.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 How so?

Comment: Nevermind, I was wrong. See achille hui's answer below for a counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even when one assume $A(t)$ is symmetric, the alternate form is still incorrect.
For a counter-example, consider

$$A(t) = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\\1 & 0 & t\\0 & t & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

We have

$$\frac{d}{dt} S(t) = 
\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 1\\0 & 2t & 0\\1 & 0 & 2t\end{bmatrix}
\ne
\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 2\\0 & 2t & 0\\0 & 0 & 2t\end{bmatrix}
= 2A(t)\frac{d}{dt}A(t)$$

Comment: Nice. I guess the mistake one makes when one believes the result holds is to assume that if B and C are symmetric then BC would be symmetric (with B=dA/dt and C=A^T).

Answer (score 3):

Short answer : no.

Think about the $ij$ entry of $A^T A$; it's

$$
s_{ij} = \sum_k a_{ki} a_{kj}
$$
Take the derivative with respect to $t$ (using primes to denote that) to get
$$
s'_{ij} = \sum_k a_{ki}' a_{kj} + \sum_k a_{ki} a_{kj}'
$$
The claim is that this is just $2 \sum_k a_{ki}' a_{kj}$, after some index-shuffling, and that's true if the matrix is symmetric, and not necessarily true otherwise.

Details: let's write that out in the case of a $3 \times 3$ matrix, with $i = 1$ and $j = 2$. We have

\begin{align}
s'_{1,2} 
&= \sum_k a_{k1}' a_{k2} + \sum_k a_{k1} a_{k2}'\\
&= (a_{1,1}' a_{1,2} +a_{2,1}' a_{2,2} +a_{3,1}' a_{3,2}) + 
(a_{1,1} a_{1,2}' +a_{2,1} a_{2,2}' +a_{3,1} a_{3,2}') \\ 
\end{align}
Those two don't look equal, do they? Let's try a concrete example.

\begin{align}
A &= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & t \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix} \\
A^t A &= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ t & 2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & t \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & t \\ t & t^2 +4\end{bmatrix} \\
(A^t A)' &= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 2t\end{bmatrix} \\
A'^t A &= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & t \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & t\end{bmatrix} \\
A^t A' &= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ t & 2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & t\end{bmatrix} \\
A'^t A + A^t A' &= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 2t\end{bmatrix} 
\end{align}

Clearly the last expression is different from  $2A^t A'$. So the formula is not correct.

(My apologies for the glib response earlier; I hope my working out the details makes up for it.)

On the other hand, if the matrix is symmetric, I'm pretty sure everything works out OK. :)

{Actually not -- see comments. The example of $s_{12}'$ makes that pretty clear: $a_{3,1}'$ appears in the left group of three, but neither it nor $a_{1,3}'$ appears in the right group of three.}

Comment: I appreciate your help, but if you feel like giving more, I have spent alot of time looking at exactly the equation you finish with, but I just can't see how to do the requisite index shuffling.  If the second term were known to be symmetric, it would be obvious.  But I don't see why I can conclude that it is symmetric.  Thanks.

Comment: See edits (in a moment).

Comment: "On the other hand, if the matrix is symmetric, I'm pretty sure everything works out OK" Actually, no.

Comment: Right you are, Did. Looking at the expression for the worked out 3x3 case, things obviously *don't* work out.

Comment: You might want to mention the fact at the beginning of your post.

Comment: Thanks. I've done that now.